# Discord bot responde a sí mismo con el comando slash

Tags: python, discord.py

estoy programando un bot para discord, y tengo un problemita y cuando escribo el comando dentro de discord el bot responde se auto responde  y no se como solucionar este problema

Este es el código que estoy usando...

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", description="ayuda bot")  # Comando
bot.remove_command("help")  # Borra el comando por defecto !help

slash = SlashCommand(bot)


@slash.slash(
    name="swf",
    description="swf habbo hotel",
    options=[
        create_option(
            name="asda",
            description="Escribe el nombre del furni",
            option_type=3,
            required=True,
        )
    ],
)
async def _swf(ctx: SlashContext, idswf):
    response = requests.get(
        f"https://apihabbo.com/api/furnis?hotel=es&name={idswf}"
    )
    data = response.json()

    for d in data["data"]:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=f"hi", description=d["code"], color=discord.Colour.random()
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)


bot.run("XxXx")
```

Me gustaría que no pasara esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

eso esto lo que deberia de ocurrir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con el código que nos pasas no es posible saber cómo funciona el bot, poco podemos ayudar. Entiendo que no es que el bot se responda a sí mismo, sino que lo que quieres es que sólo emita una respuesta con toda la información. Para eso tendrías que crear el mensaje empotrado (embed) con [múltiples campos](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.add_field).